# How to make a cryptographic algorithm less reverse engineerable?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

i have developed an AES256 encryption application with but i want to make it more secure. How can i understand how easy it is to reverse engineer and how can i make it less reverse engineerable ?

Note  : it would be great if you recommend me some reverse engineering books.

code: http://pastebin.com/uiuBNJ0y

code: for the citizens of countries which has banned pastebin. http://paste.ubuntu.com/22563333/

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to rely on obfuscating the algorithm for security. It's better to be completely open about the encryption algorithm, but have very secure keys, such that even if someone knows how to encrypt/decrypt, he cannot do it when he doesn't have the key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is os.urandom(32) secure enough? How can i make it more secure?

Comment: 32 bits sounds like too little. I read on Wikipedia about AES: The design and strength of all key lengths of the AES algorithm (i.e., 128, 192 and 256) are sufficient to protect classified information up to the SECRET level. TOP SECRET information will require use of either the 192 or 256 key lengths.

Comment: This is what i get when i change the 32: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22568732/

Comment: I just remembered, 32 byte is required because 256 bit = 32 byte. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the Python label, I guess your algorithm is written in Python. You could use [my obfuscator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Opy) to make your algorithm hard to decipher. It's one way only.

Don't rely on distributing only the .pyc files. They can be trivially reverse engineered without manual intervention even.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment but i got an error.

I followed these steps:
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install

after that i moved my program to opy folder and python3 opy.py 
a folder named opy_opy created when i try to launch my program by writing python3 l11l111l_opy_.py it gaves me this error:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/22566848/

what should i do?

Comment: I don't see any description of the error in the report. Best you switch off string obfuscation in the config file.

Comment: File "l111ll11_opy_.py", line 72
    l111l1l1_opy_('[
                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal                                          

now i get this error :/

Comment: Hi, there are a lot of reasons why it doesn't work. On the download page look at the 'known limitations', especially no # inside a string, e.g. replace it by *. And you use many external modules, which you have to mention in the config file under 'external_modules'. (Or mention the identifiers you use form them under 'plain_names').